# Simple jQuery .change question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and am having difficulty getting a .change event to call a named function.  When I use an anonymous function, it works fine.

This works fine:

```
$(function() {

    $("select").change(function() {
        alert("hello");
    }); 
});
```

This does not work (i.e. has not effect):

```
$(function() {
    $("select").change(processSelection());
    function processSelection() {alert('Hello!');}; 
});
```

Any assistance much appreciated!

Comment: Curiously, when I remove the parentheses from the function call, it does work.  I.e. I change processSelection() to processSelection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the function as an argument, not calling it, so you don't need the `()` after `processSelection`. So, you should do

```
$("select").change(processSelection);
```

instead of

```
$("select").change(processSelection());
```

Comment: You should explain the difference, just in case it's not obvious to everyone.